# Which department work is being carried out for

Tags: word-choice, british-english

I am a non-English-speaking software developer who faces difficulties with the English language.

I built a form for users submitting work for my department. The users should write down their name and the department the work will be done for. This field is labeled 'Department'. The problem is that they are putting my department as they think that is the department that will carry out the work. How should it be labeled correctly? 'Your department' seems incorrect, 'benefitting department' does not sound correct but it would be the closest to what I have in my mother tongue.

Comment: If you want them to put down their dept. then "Your Department" seems the most logical.

Comment: But they might be submitting work for not their department.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "department the work is to be done for".

Comment: Labels on the forms are short and snappy not because they need to be, but due to fact that very often there is very limited space and line break is not an option.

Comment: As you say you have "difficulties with the English language", you might find [ell.se] helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **Department (Submitted for)** with "submitted for" in parenthesis.This kind of usage is perfectly usable for form fields where there is a chance of ambiguity.

In case you also need to know the person's current department you may similarly add another field Department(Contributor's department).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a "target department"?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Generally best to explain your answers, here.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure to have understood.

Perhaps you mean "Recipient Department", or "Assigned Department", perhaps "Allocated Department" - that is the Department which will take advantage of a work. "Assigned Department" could also mean the one which has to do the job.